# iTextSharp - How to convert PdfPTable to JPEG?

Tags: c#, .net, itext

iTextSharp - How to convert PdfPTable to JPEG or other image format?

Comment: have you tried http://www.ghostscript.com/?

Answer (score 2):

I believe iTextSharp does not currently support rendering PDF into image files. Ghostscript supports converting PDF files to images. There is a good tutorial [here](http://www.mattephraim.com/blog/2009/01/06/a-simple-c-wrapper-for-ghostscript/) available to convert PDF files to images.  Also you can use rendering object like [this](http://imageresizing.net/plugins/pdfrenderer) one.

Answer (score 2):

iTextSharp is only for creating PDF Documents.
There are many other DLL's that can be used to convert PDF to JPG. The most preferred is Ghostscript(GS). you can use the foll. C# Code with GS dll

```
public static void PdfToJpg(string input, string output)
  {
      PdfToImage.PDFConvert pp = new PDFConvert();
      pp.OutputFormat = "jpeg"; //format
      pp.JPEGQuality = 100; //100% quality
      pp.ResolutionX = 300; //dpi
      pp.ResolutionY = 300;
      pp.FirstPageToConvert = 1; //pages you want
      pp.LastPageToConvert = 1;
      pp.Convert(input ,  output ); 
  }
namespace PdfToJpeg
{
 {
    PDFConvert converter = new PDFConvert();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
     try
     {
PdfToJpg("c:\abc.pdf","c:\" + "output.jpg");
MessageBox.Show("Files Converted");
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
MessageBox.Show("Exception Error Occured... " + ex.Message.ToString());
     }
  }
 }
```

Comment: I have same request. Any advice what `PDFConvert` is? Or if you say it is the GhostScript project, please can you refer to any URL how to use it?